# Concatenate formula with rowcount

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to enter a `CONCATENATE` formula in a cell with VBA. But the result it writes keep returning false... I need to use a rowcount, since the table grows longer and I need it for THAT row.

This is the latest code I tried, again to no avail:

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = Formula = "=CONCATENATE(P" & RowCount & "J" & RowCount & "DG" & RowCount
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) You are missing your commas in your concatenate formula; (2) I can't see where RowCount is defined - is that not simply the total count of all rows in a worksheet? ie: 1M? I doubt this is what you want; (3) Look into .FormulaR1C1; it allows you to write formulas relative to a given cell's position, which seems to be ideal for you.

Comment: Of course... Commas. 
Yes, rowcount is defined elsewhere. 
R1C1 I need to dive into for sure. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating your string properly and you need to change `= Formula =` to `.Formula =`. Also, I'm assuming `RowCount` is defined somewhere?

Change:

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = Formula = "=CONCATENATE(P" & RowCount & "J" & RowCount & "DG" & RowCount
```

To:

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(P" & RowCount & ",J" & RowCount & ",DG" & RowCount & ")"
```

Comment: @ Bond, I tried your suggestion and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use R1C1 addressing instead:

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(R[-1]C16,R[-1]C10,R[-1]C111)"
```

Comment: @Chis.Wisselo I recommend you look at this one; this may look a little confusing at first but knowing how to use this notation can be very valuable in the long run. Note how in this case, it completely eliminates the need to even use the RowCount variable.

Comment: Yes, I think it can be simpler using this. But why the R[-1]? Does that look at the row above?

Comment: Yes, it does. Since you're offsetting by `rowcount`, you want to look one row up.